# input-append class button shows with a margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi StackOverflow community, i'm building a site based on twitter bootstrap 2.0.4 in certain page i want to attach a button to an input. the problem is that show with a margin between the input and the button.

i'm sure that is something i'm missing, but i can't determine what it is ?

**EDIT**: Some styles like disabled and uneditable-input are not applying correctly in the page

**EDIT 2**: Apparently working .disabled and .uneditable-input.

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sHGtb/

JFiddle Fullscreen result: http://jsfiddle.net/sHGtb/embedded/result/

any help ??

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/test/index.php/../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/test/index.php/../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../../js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/index.php/../js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <hr/>
                <h4>Puesto</h4>
                <p>Debe estar asignado segun su perfil, solo los administradores pueden cambiar esta opcion; si existiese alguna irregularidad debe solicitar reportelo al administardor.</p>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="puesto" class="control-label">Puesto</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <input type="text" name="puesto" class="input-xlarge" />
                            <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/index.php/../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/index.php/../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Could you create a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help us answer your question?

Comment: sure why not ... working on it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might sound very dumb but don't leave a new line between the input and the button your text editor is messing with the page :-P

```
      <div class="control-group">
                <label for="puesto" class="control-label">Puesto</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append">
                        <input type="text" name="puesto" class="input-xlarge" /><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: There is a space (or other char) between the components and I bet that your page is UTF-8

Comment: Ok. ubern00b mistake, danm it!

Comment: you award the bounty reward , my friend only that can be applied tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to eliminate the margin between the button and the input field?
You can try something like this...

```
<input type="text" name="puesto" class="input-xlarge" style="margin-right:0;"/>
<button class="btn" type="button" style="margin-left:0;"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

If that styling doesn't work experiment with some more css styling on the elements.

Comment: it's supposed that twitter bootstrap supports this without any hack ... and i'm following the rules, the problem is still following the directions the element isn't showing well... i'm only want to begin to hack the css as last resort