# Why's there space between prepended icon and input field with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, markup

Using Twitter's Bootstrap, I have a form with an input field and a prepended icon:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <label for="some_name">What's your ...</label>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-road"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="span2" name="some[name]" id="some_name"/>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I haven't changed Bootstrap's CSS as of yet. The examples show no such space between icon and input field. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11367746/1478467 (and certainly many others)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it out myself: Don't break lines between icon markup and `input`:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <label for="some_name">What's your ...</label>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-road"></i></span><input type="text" class="span2" name="some[name]" id="some_name"/>
</div>
```

As Twitter themselves explain it [in the icons documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons):

> When using beside strings of text, as in buttons or nav links, be sure to leave a space after the  tag for proper spacing.

That was my clue.

Comment: Note: As of Bootstrap 2.1.0, this is no longer necessary (see http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/08/20/bootstrap-2-1-0-released/).